# Accessing a method while iterating over mutable borrow in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator, borrow-checker

I have this piece of code below where I iterate over a `Vec` (`self.regions`), and under the right conditions, I mutate the current element of the `Vec`

However, when processing a `region`, I must also call another method on `self` that borrows it, causing me to have both a mutable and shared reference of `self` at the same time, which is obviously impossible (and will not compile)

How can I change my code in order to make it work ?

I've thought of moving line 3 outside the loop and using a `iter()` instead of an `iter_mut()`, but then I don't see how to "keep the two iterators in sync" in order to make sure that both pieces of code refer to the same region

```
fn growth(&'a mut self) {
   for region in self.regions.iter_mut() {
       let candidates = self.neighbors(region); // Has to involve taking a &self
       // Do stuff with `candidates` that involves mutating `region`
   }
}
```

## Edit

My post was lacking context, so here is the full function. `self.regions` is of type `Vec<Vec<&'a Cell>>`, and the signature of `neighbors` is `fn neighbors(&self, region: &Vec<&Cell>) -> HashSet<&Cell>`.

The objective of my program is to tesselate a grid into random polyominoes, by randomly selecting some sources and (the part that I posted) "growing them" into regions by iterating over each region and adding a random neighbor of the region to the region itself.

The `neighbors` function depends of the previous iterations' outcome, so it cannot be precomputed

```
    fn growth(&'a mut self) -> bool {
        let mut unchoosen_cells = 20; // More complex in reality
        let mut steps: usize = 0;

        while unchoosen_cells != 0 {
            if steps > GROWTH_STEP_LIMIT { return false; }
            for region in self.regions.iter_mut() {
                if rand::random() { continue; }

                let candidates = self.neighbors(region);
                if let Some(cell) = candidates.iter().choose(&mut thread_rng()) {
                    // cell.in_region = true;
                    region.push(cell);
                    unchoosen_cells -= 1;
                }
                steps += 1;
            }
        }
        true
    }
```

Comment: You can't. Having a shared & a mutable reference to the same object is [undefined behavior (section on aliasing)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html). You might have luck copying the region or candidates, but we're lacking context to be able to determine a solution.

Comment: Maybe the best way to solve your issue would be to [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) the vector `self.regions` (which is relatively cheap, since `Vec::default()` does not allocate!), operate on it (which, maybe, won't interfere with `region`), then put it back into `self.regions`.

Comment: It seems obligatory at this point to point out that keeping references to `self` in `self.cells` is [very hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) and you should probably look for some other solution. (I assume that's what `neighbors` is doing.)

Comment: @jthulhu i think that would work, but how do i put it back ? i've tried adding `mem::replace(&mut self.regions, regions);` just before the 2 possible code path ends, but i still get an error about having shared and mutable references at the same time (with the definition of `candidates`, even though the scopes are clearly distinct

Comment: @clino then I think your design is just doomed.

Comment: You may want to refactor your code to use region _indices_ so that you can limit borrows from `self.regions` to the smallest possible scope. In the context of your `growth` function, this would mean iterating over the indices of `self.region` and making the `neighbors` function take in a region index rather than a region reference.

Answer (score 1):

After reading all the comments, I understand that my issue is the result of a poor design, and I will refactor my code in order to use indices instead of references

Thanks to all the people who took the time to help me, and I'm marking this as solved